# HTML5 Audio Some Sounds Doesn't Play

Tags: android, html, mp3, html5-audio

I am creating a HTML5 game. I have several mp3 sounds. When I play the game in Chrome on my desktop, all of the sounds play. When I play the game on my mobile device and use Chrome, some of the sounds play and some of them don't. Could there be something wrong with the way the mp3 files were created?

This is how I create the audio.

```
var audio = new Audio(filePath);
audio.volume = 0.75;
myAudio.push(audio);
```

Later on in the game I want to play the file.

```
myAudio[0].play();
```

This is the format for how I do all of my audio.

Answer (score 0):

I have determined that the issue with mobile is it will only let me play the audio if it is caused by an user input. The sounds that were not playing, were the ones that the code would start itself. The sounds that worked, were the ones caused by user input.